# Django retain order of product when displayed

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Suppose I want the order of my products in my Django webshop to be displayed in a certain order. How can I achieve that? I have simplified the below example to show the problems that I am experiencing. In my webshop models I have the below 2 models.

```
class TakeawayWebshop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, help_text = 'name of takeaway restaurant')
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=0, default=0.00)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

In the admin.py I have

```
class TakeawayWebshopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TakeawayWebshopAdminForm
    list_display = ['name']
    ordering = ['name']
    filter_horizontal = ('products',)

admin.site.register(TakeawayWebshop, TakeawayWebshopAdmin)
```

Now from the admin, I am adding 3 products in the *exact* order of product A, product B and product C to the webshop using the `filter_horizontal`. [image: product added the exact order]. Upon saving the `TakeawayWebshop` model object, the products in the `filter_horizontal` box automatically rearanged, so the order becomes product C, product B and product A.

When from the `views.py` if I get a list of all the products I have added to the webshop such as

```
webshop = TakeawayWebshop.objects.filter(name = 'my webshop name')[0]
products = webshop.products.all()
```

The queryset returned is

```
<QuerySet [<Product: Product C>, <Product: Product B>, <Product: Product A>]>
```

Obviously I guess I am using the wrong strategy in trying to make the products in query set appear in the order that I originally intend them to be arranged (product A, product B and product C) when inserting them into the filter_horizontal box. Also I am wondering if it is possible to rearrange the order that products in filter_horizontal box appear?

Comment: you can create a datetime column and order based on the datetime of product added

Comment: Do you mean a datetime field in the Product model? I don't think it will record datetime of when the product was added.